# Javascript filter quotation mark - error

Tags: javascript, json, api, filter

I am writing JSON API call where I am getting html string

ie:

```
"content":"<p>Being a designer is like being a porn star. 
You&#8217;re hot &#038; popular for a year or two, 
then everyone goes off and finds something new to screw around too.  <\/p>\n"
```

I need to get this string without HTML, so I am using this:

`n = e.content.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "")`

but when in string is Right single quotation mark `’ &#8217;` it will end the string.

Please, how can I filter/replace this quotation mark together with other symbols? When I added quotation mark, it stopped filtering everything.

Comment: Is the content always a single HTML tag containing the encoded text you wish to retrieve?

Comment: *but when in string is Right single quotation mark ’ &#8217; it will end the string.* I don't understand this sentence. what do you mean? Anyway, the solution is to create a new element, set this as `innerHTML`, then take its `textContent`.

Comment: @torazaburo thank you very much, `textContent` solved it `x = document.getElementById("quote-content").textContent;`